# Read AWS s3 Bucket Name from CloudWatch Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on writing a Lambda function that triggers when a new s3 bucket is created. I have a cloudwatch function that triggers the lambda function. I see the open to pass the whole event to the lambda function as input. When I this, how do I get my Lambda function to read the bucket's name from the event and assign the name as the value to a string variable?

Here is what my code looks like:

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

s3 = boto3.client('s3')  

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket = event['s3']['bucket']['name']
```

Comment: Hey @Woodrow, When I try     
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    I get   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
KeyError: 'Records'

Answer (score 2):

CloudTrail events of S3 bucket level operations have different format than the one posted by @Woodrow. Actually, the name of bucket is within a JSON object called `requestParameters`. Moreover, the whole event is encapsulated within `Records` array.  See [CloudTrail Log Event Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference.html)

Truncated version of CloudTrail event for bucket creation

```js
"eventSource": "s3.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "CreateBucket",
"userAgent": "signin.amazonaws.com",
"requestParameters": {
    "CreateBucketConfiguration": {
        "LocationConstraint": "aws-region",
        "xmlns": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"
    },
    "bucketName": "my-awsome-bucket"
}
```

Therefore, your code could look something like:

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

s3 = boto3.client('s3')  

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        if record['eventName'] == "CreateBucket":
            bucket = record['requestParameters']['bucketName']
            print(bucket)
```

Comment: Hi,I am having the Lambda function triggered by a CloudWatch Create Bucket event:  Here is what the trigger looks like:   {
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateBucket"
    ]
  }
}